# tensorflow dynamically extending list of placeholders

Tags: python, tensorflow, placeholder, lstm

I would like to dynamically extend list of placeholders at every iteration of the graph. At the time of graph creation I have to define variable_length which is used in the for loop and then I can accordingly feed the data to the placeholders. I tried to use `tf.while_loop` and I could extend the list of placeholders, however the feeding process is done before this `tf.while_loop` and an error occurs:

```
Error: "list index is out of range"
```

code:

```
   self._train_data = []
    for _ in range( variable_length ):
        placeholder_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[self._batch_size, self._input_size])    
        self._train_data.append(placeholder_input)
```

The execution and feeding is done as below

```
feed_dict = dict()
for i in range(self._num_unrollings + 1):
   feed_dict[self._train_data[i]] = batches[i]

_, loss_reduced = self._session.run([ self._optimizer, self._loss_reduced], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Comment: Modifying graph between session runs calls give a significant performance penalty, what about creating all of the placeholders ahead of time using `tf.placeholder_with_default` and only feeding some of them?

Comment: How exactly would 'tf.placeholder_with_default' work in my case? I wrote my implementation of LSTM cell. For now I define number of unrollings and feed data for example only for 20 unrollings. I would like to feed the whole batch at once but batches have different lengths. After that I will be able to perform different operations. Theoretically I could append to batches specific number and make them of equal size but then I need to create some mask, moreover multiplication in that case would be a big waste.

Comment: Let's say that I created a list of 'tf.placeholder_with_default'. How do I extract then in the graph the placeholders for which the value was feed, not default.